# Save bones position after rotation in xna

Tags: c#, xna, rotation

I'm developping a game for solving a rubik's cube in xna framework c#. I want to know how to save bones positions after rotating them. I'm calling this method to draw a bone that constructs the face side of the cube.

```
protected void DrawModel()
{
    cube.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(modelTransforms);
    ModelMeshCollection cubes = cube.Meshes;
    List<string> yellowFace = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < cubes.Count; i++)
    {
        if (cubes.ElementAt(i).Name.ToString().Contains("F"))
        {
            yellowFace.Add(cubes.ElementAt(i).Name.ToString());
        }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < yellowFace.Count; j++)
    {

        foreach (BasicEffect eff in cubes[yellowFace.ElementAt(j)].Effects)
        {
            eff.View = View;
            eff.Projection = Projection;
            eff.EnableDefaultLighting();
            degree = (float)degree;
            if (xtan <= degree)
            {

                eff.World = Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(new Vector3(0, 0, 1), -xtan);


            }




        }


        cubes[yellowFace.ElementAt(j)].Draw();

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < cubes.Count; i++)
    {
        if (cubes.ElementAt(i).Name.ToString().Contains("F"))
        {
            continue;

        }
        else
        {
            foreach (BasicEffect eff in cubes.ElementAt(i).Effects)
            {
                eff.View = View;


                eff.World = Matrix.Identity;



                eff.Projection = Projection;
                eff.EnableDefaultLighting();
            }
            cubes.ElementAt(i).Draw();
        }

    }




}
```

After I run the game, the rotation is running good but once it's done, the game reloads the bones as they looked at the start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi everyone to save bones position after rotation you have to transform them in the matrix transform

```
//this before the drawing loop
model.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(modelTransforms);
//drawing loop .... 
//basiceffect loop
......
//after basiceffect loop
Matrix rotationmatrix = Matrix.CreateRotationX(angle);
// X,Y Z are the axis , angle is the rotaion value
mesh.parentbone.Transform = rotationmatrix * mesh.parentbone.transform;

//end drawing loop
```

I hope that this help everyone 
thank you